# aligning menu and display DIVs in parent page DIV

Tags: html, css

I have built a simple example of a page with left-fixed-width menu and a right DIV that is used for displaying the pages content. They all enter into the #main div, which is set to take 100% of the whole page.

I need the menu and the display page to be side-by-side, and the menu to be always fixed at 100px and the display DIV to adapt all the time to the remaining space.

Here's my code so far

```css
#main {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

#menu {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #555;
}

#display {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='menu'>menu <br><br><br><br></div>
  <div id='display'>lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page <br><br><br><br></div>

</div>
```

so they display ok so far, but i need the 2 children DIVs aligned side by side

thanks !

i'd love it if it would be possible to do **without** table-cell or flex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `100px` to `#menu` so assign remaining space to `#display`

```
#display {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #888;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: is this "calc" CSS function avail all through the main browsers ?

Comment: All browsers support `calc()` Check with this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Comment: it works perfectly :) but now I have another issue..the fixed 100px div can be expanded if I click on the "menu" button, to show not only icons, but also the descriptive title near each icon...when I click to expand it, the fixed DIV is not pushing the content to the right...how should I approach this ?

Comment: it's toooo long and it needs to be edited out of PHP conditions.....basically i need to click on a button and extend the fixed 100px child to say 200px...when I click back the menu button, it should collapse the #menu again to its 100px size

Comment: So in `click` function expand mode add some class and assign `#display` css with `width: calc(100% - 200px);` then remove that class when expand is closed

Comment: it's beggining to take shape. What a wonderful ideea to add classes dynamically, depending on the need, with .className :) thanks bro, you really saved my day

Comment: Got the answer...!

Answer (score 1):

That's true as suggested you need to you `CSS calc()` function to minus the fixed width of `#menu`, for other set `height` as `auto` and `100%`. Use either `float` or `display:inline-block`, you have included both.

```css
#main {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  display: block;
}

#menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
}

#display {
  background-color: #888;
  width: calc(100% - 105px);
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='menu'>menu
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id='display'>lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page lorem ipsum display page</div>
</div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc0j0y46/), scale to front and back to see auto-increase in height of parent div.

Comment: now i ran into an other problem... my #menu of 100px only displays a vertical list of icons. If I click on the "menu" button, another DIV opens up to the right of the icons showing the menu itself, written in text. This one is not pushing the 100px menu to the right, it displays on top....messsy

Comment: @AdrianTanase Can't guess.  As you asked current styling adapt the remaining space. Could help if you would have added your scripting codes. Or you could use jQuery to expand and collapse your menu.

Comment: it's beginning to work, now just have to fix some glitches cause of padding and margins, but it's actually working. See the ideea at the answer below, where I should add dynamically a className with Javascript when clicking on the "menu" button, each class having the needed sizes for the menu and display (when opened or close) :) thanks !

Comment: @AdrianTanase That's great and nice approach. Welcome :-)